# wifi doesn't work upgrading to 20.04

Tags: wireless, lenovo, 20.04

I have a Lenovo 530S, which was perfectly running on 19.10.
But after upgrading to 20.04 - not a fresh install - wifi doesn't work.
No network can be seen, after a very short period of time after initialization. So, I've tested 2 initialization pendrives and:
1) with same 20.04, had exactly the same problem;
2) with 19.10 worked fine, as used to be on same version installed.
On Ubuntu 20.04 installed, the command
`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`  returns

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)  
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci  
    Kernel modules: rtwpci  
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp Device   [15b7:5005] (rev 01)  
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: yes  
    Hard blocked: no  
2: hci0: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: yes  
    Hard blocked: no  
3: phy0: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You made a typo, you missed a dash before `A3`. Please fix it.

Comment: Sure @Pilot6, I've made the correction, thanks.